# Possible to style only the leftmost tab page on an asp tab container

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a standard asp tab container from the ajax control toolkit:

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="tcMain" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
Width="99%" min-width="900px" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="TabStyle">
```

But the design of the page means that I want to style the left most tab header one way, the middle few the same, and the right most, slightly differently. Namely, to create rounded edges on the two "outward" tab pages.

I've played around with the .ajax__tab_hover .ajax__tab_outer type css things, but I can't seem to figure out a way to manipulate them to do what I want.

Does anyone have any ideas/examples of how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Hi now you can used multiclass in your design as like this

**your html**

```
<div class="wraper">
<div class="left" id="someid"></div>
<div class="left center"></div>
<div class="left right"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wraper{
overflow:hidden;
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.left{
width:33%;
height:100px;
float:left;
}
.left#someid{
background:red;
}
.left.center{
background:green;
}
.left.right{
background:yellow;
}
```

***[Demo live](http://tinkerbin.com/ymeLuwvq)***

Comment: Rohit Azad, that's great. I'll have a look at see if it will work with the ajax tool kit tab control. I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: Rohit Azad, that doesn't seem to work with the structure of the ajax toolkit tab container control. Not that I can get to work anyway. Within the container I have a few tab panels, and its just the first one that I want to style. Within the container I have a number of tabs (below)

`<asp:TabPanel ID="tpOutstanding" runat="server" HeaderText="Outstanding">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Outstanding
                    </HeaderTemplate>`

But they just don't seem to respond to individual styles.